# How to change telegram bot command action?

Tags: telegram-bot

How do I assert an action to a command in a telegram bot?

[Here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/features#commands) it is shown how commands work.
[Here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/features#edit-bots) it is shown how to change **list** of commands.

But how to change the commands **themselves**?

I.e. how to create a command '/help', which will show user a message 'hi, this is help'?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I assert an action to a command in a telegram bot?

The straightforward way is using the *Edit Commands* option from the @BotFather:

[image]

Multiple commands can be passed as multiple lines, for example, when asked, reply to the BotFather with:

```
pause       - Pause
play        - Play
```

To set those 2 commands with their explanation.

---

- Your bot can do this by himself using the [`setMyCommands`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setmycommands) REST API method
- A command may not start with a capitalised letter